# How do I add user input to a list and total up that list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm running a program that tracks the user's expenses. I've gotten most of it complete but need the most crucial part. When I run the program I get an error message of a1 not being defined. Here's what I have:

```
class Expense(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        home = Label(self, text = "Home: ")
        home.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        util = Label(self, text = "Utilities: ")
        util.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
        health = Label(self, text = "Health/Medical: ")
        health.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
        food = Label(self, text = "Food: ")
        food.grid(row = 6, column = 0)
        transport = Label(self, text = "Transportation: ")
        transport.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
        
        a1 = Entry(self).grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        a2 = Entry(self).grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        a3 = Entry(self).grid(row = 5, column = 1)
        a4 = Entry(self).grid(row = 6, column = 1)
        a5 = Entry(self).grid(row = 7, column = 1)
        
        submit = Button(self, text = "Submit", command = self.AddExpenses)
        submit.grid(row = 8, column = 1)

    #Here's where I run an issue.
    def AddExpenses(self):
        expenses = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
        total = 0
        for i in list:
            total = total + i
        print("Your total spent", total)
```

Comment: Well, yes, `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5` are local variables of the `__init__`, so they are inaccessible outside this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments to your code.

- You should generally use `import tkinter as tk` instead of `from tkinter import *`, in order not to pollute your namespace and having potential conflicts between names
- When defining widgets in tkinter, you can only assign them to a variable before calling `pack` or `grid`, as these functions return `None`
- You only need to assign a widget to a variable if you wish to reuse it later in your code
- You cannot use your variables `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5` in a new function because that function doesn't know about them (they were defined in another function - the `__init__`). To retrieve them elsewhere, you need to assign them to your class instance through the `self` object.
- When you wish to get the value from your entries in the `AddExpense` function, you need to call the `get()` method to retrieve them

With that in mind, you could try the code below to get what you want

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Expense(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        tk.Label(self, text="Home: ").grid(row=3, column=0)
        tk.Label(self, text="Utilities: ").grid(row=4, column=0)
        tk.Label(self, text="Health/Medical: ").grid(row=5, column=0)
        tk.Label(self, text="Food: ").grid(row=6, column=0)
        tk.Label(self, text="Transportation: ").grid(row=7, column=0)

        self.a1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.a1.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.a2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.a2.grid(row=4, column=1)

        self.a3 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.a3.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.a4 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.a4.grid(row=6, column=1)

        self.a5 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.a5.grid(row=7, column=1)

        tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.AddExpenses).grid(row=8, column=1)

    def AddExpenses(self):
        expenses = [self.a1.get(), self.a2.get(), self.a3.get(), self.a4.get(), self.a5.get()]
        total = sum(map(float, expenses))
        messagebox.showinfo("Expenses", f"Your total spent is: {total}")
        print(f"Your total spent is {total}")

root = tk.Tk()
exp = Expense(root, None)
exp.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using classes you need to use instance variables to be able to use that variables throughout the class.

You need to use `self` keyword infront of all those variables. Like:

```
class Expense(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
```

that's just an example.

You should change the code to this:

```
class Expense(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.home = Label(self, text = "Home: ")
        self.home.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        self.util = Label(self, text = "Utilities: ")
        self.util.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
        self.health = Label(self, text = "Health/Medical: ")
        self.health.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
        self.food = Label(self, text = "Food: ")
        self.food.grid(row = 6, column = 0)
        self.transport = Label(self, text = "Transportation: ")
        self.transport.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
        
        self.a1 = Entry(self)
        self.a2 = Entry(self)
        self.a3 = Entry(self)
        self.a4 = Entry(self)
        self.a5 = Entry(self)

        self.a1.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        self.a2.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        self.a3.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
        self.a4.grid(row = 6, column = 1)
        self.a5.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
        
        self.submit = Button(self, text = "Submit", command = self.AddExpenses)
        self.submit.grid(row = 8, column = 1)

    #Here's where I run an issue.
    def AddExpenses(self):
        expenses = [
                    self.a1.get(),
                    self.a2.get(),
                    self.a3.get(),
                    self.a4.get(),
                    self.a5.get(),
        ]

        total = 0
        for i in list:
            total = total + i
        print("Your total spent", total)
```

If you are new to Object Oriented Programming with python you should focus on learning that first, else `Tkinter` is going to get harder.

Comment: There are several more issues in OPs code which are not addressed in your answer, so this certainly wont work

Comment: @oskros I just answered his issue with not being able to access his own variables, the rest should be fairly easy to figure out on his own.

Comment: Not if you dont know that `grid` is a void function returning `None`, or the fact that you need to call `get` to extract the values from an entry

Comment: @oskros Thanks for pointing it out, I didn't pay much attention to his code, I only went on to solve his `self.` issue and just added `self.` to every variable declaration without reading the code sorry. I'll make some edits and can you help me to point his mistakes out.